# Закодировать комбинацию двоичного простого кода двоичными кодами

Tags: кодировка, обработка-ошибок

Доброго времени суток. Есть поставленая задача: закодировать комбинацию двоичного простого кода двоичными кодами, которые обнаруживают ошибки.
Есть число А (001010100100), и есть обозначение кодов (с проверкой на четность и корреляционный). Как закодировать число А этими проверками? Количество ошибок которое находится первым и вторым способом 1/1.
Сам пробовал делать, но толкового ничего не вышло. Есть пример. Если нужно, могу скинуть. Для меня тм начего не понятно. Прошу помощи!)

UPD: для проверки на четность, должно быть четное количество единиц, по типу:

1001111 --> 10011111
. Что мне тогда делать со своим кодом, если у меня уже есть четное количество единиц? (001010100100)

Comment: К преподу за помощью обращались и не помогло?

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов обращался. Она просто сказала что там все легко и делается за пол часа. А потом ушла. Уже третий день мучаюсь

Answer (score 0):

Помогла книга "Кодирование информации (двоичные коды). Березюк Н. Т., Андрущенко А. Г., Мощицкий С. С."

В корреляционном методе двоичный код меняется 0 на 01 а 1 на 10 соответственно. В таком случае, вместо k=7 чисел в коде, будет k*2, т.е. в два раза больше.

В проверке на парность нужно просто сделать парное количество единиц. Если единиц будет не парное количество, то просто добавляется единица в конец кода. Если парное, то ноль.

Оказалось все довольно просто.